# Is there a way to save a query in django and use it later?

Tags: sql, django, model, pickle

I have a service that prints the incoming data to excel. This service works exactly as follows. I'm building the query but not running it. I dump and save the query with the help of "pickle", load and use it again with pickle in the celery task. This has worked on all my models so far. But in the model below, the pickle gives an error.

django version=3.2
The Money Field I used in the model is here.
**django-money==3.0.0**

```
class PaymentStatus:
    WAIT = 1
    SUCCESS = 2
    FAIL = 3
    CANCEL = 4

    types = (
        (WAIT, _('Waiting')),
        (SUCCESS, _('Success')),
        (FAIL, _('Fail')),
        (CANCEL, _('Cancel'))
    )



class PaymentModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'betik_app_payment'
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['dt', 'user_email'])
        ]

    provider = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=PaymentProviderTypeEnum.types)
    is_test = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    payment_status = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=PaymentStatus.types, default=PaymentStatus.WAIT)
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, help_text=_('amount paid excluding tax and discount'))
    paid_price = MoneyField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, help_text=_('amount paid including tax and discount'))
    dt = models.DateTimeField()
    user_email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, help_text=_('This token comes from the payment system. With this token, inquiries are made in the payment system'))
    locale = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="en")
```

> pickle error: _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function
> QuerySet.distinct at 0x7faf69912430>: it's not the same object as
> django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

```
qs=PaymentModel.objects.filter(dt__date__lte="2030-01-01")
pickle.dumps(qs) #raise error
```

works successfully when there is only one model

```
qs=PaymentModel.objects.filter(dt__date__lte="2030-01-01")
pickle.dumps(qs[0]) # SUCCESS
```

When it didn't work that way, I decided to save raw sql and run it on a celery task.

```
qs=PaymentModel.objects.filter(dt__date__lte="2030-01-01")
sql=str(qs.query)

## raw sql ##
'SELECT "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."id", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."provider", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."is_test", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."payment_status", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."price_currency", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."price", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."paid_price_currency", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."paid_price", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."dt", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."user_email", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."token", "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."locale" FROM "betik_app_payment_paymentmodel" WHERE ("betik_app_payment_paymentmodel"."dt")::date <= 2030-01-01'
```

but when I try to run it from raw sql query it gives an error like this

```
qs=PaymentModel.objects.raw(sql)
list(qs)
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 1476, in **len**
> self._fetch_all()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 1471, in _fetch_all
> self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 1494, in iterator
> query = iter(self.query)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
> line 100, in **iter**
> self._execute_query()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
> line 140, in _execute_query
> self.cursor.execute(self.sql, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 98, in execute
> return super().execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 66, in execute
> return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
> return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90,
> in **exit**
> raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: **ERROR: operator does not exist: date
> <= integer LINE 1: ...FROM betik_app_payment_paymentmodel WHERE
> dt::date<=2030-01-...
> ^ HINT: No function
> matching the given name and argument types. You may need to add
> explicit type casts.**

Is there another way to save the query and run it later?

Answer (score 0):

- Querysets are Lazy so the database will not get hit until you evaluate your queryset. You can check this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy), it's worth it to me.

Comment: ok lazy but i want to save query and run it in task. I can't do this?